# Increase number of old kernels to keep on autoremove (in ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: 22.04

i like to do the same thing like that:

[Increase number of old kernels to keep on autoremove](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066292/increase-number-of-old-kernels-to-keep-on-autoremove)

but in ubuntu 22.04 i cant find "apt-auto-removal" file.

thanks nir

**update**:
this is the content of this dir

[dir content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LU82v.png)

and i have "01autoremove" file and this is what i have inside

/etc/apt/apt.conf.d$ cat 01autoremove

[01autoremove file content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZLDg.png)

do you know what do i need to change?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Can you edit your question with an added screenshot of the files in the directory /etc/apt/apt.conf.d? ( I use Kubuntu 20.04 and my file is called 01autoremove. )

Comment: i just add a screenshot to the question, i hope you can help me . thanks.

Comment: In 20.04 there is no "apt-auto-removal" file either. I personally use 'Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer' to uninstall old kernels. This program does not make a difference between manually and automaticly installed kernels. It works with a GUI, so it is very easy to use. After a new kernel is installed ( and after reboot works properly ) I just run the program to unistall an old kernel. You can find more info about the program and how to install it here: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/08/mainline-install-latest-kernel-ubuntu-linux-mint/ . imo easier than changing a bunch of scripts.

Answer (score 3):

To keep additional kernels I think you would have to essentially duplicate the `apt-auto-removal` script concept.  Have a script that runs and generates an apt configuration specifying what to keep in an `APT::NeverAutoRemove` block.  You might even be able to simply download the old `apt-auto-removal` script into `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/` and patch it to keep the number of kernels you want, but I have not tested that.

The `apt-auto-removal` script was removed from the `apt` package recently, and the logic for protecting kernels from autoremove was added into `apt` itself.  There were some edge cases that the script did not handle properly because it was only run when a kernel was installed.  From the `apt` [changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/a/apt/apt_2.4.5/changelog).

```
apt (2.1.16) unstable; urgency=medium
...
  * Rewrite of the kernel autoremoval code:
    - Determine autoremovable kernels at run-time (LP: #1615381), this fixes the
      issue where apt could consider a running kernel autoremovable
    - Automatically remove unused kernels on apt {full,dist}-upgrade.
      This helps ensuring that we don't run out of /boot space.
    - Only keep up to 3 (not 4) kernels.
      Ubuntu boot partitions were sized for 3 kernels, not 4.
...
 -- Julian Andres Klode <jak@debian.org>  Fri, 08 Jan 2021 21:49:15 +0100
```

Based on the `apt` [source code](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/blob/edffb0ae26935d948ffeb3be229fdcf37d2a1ee1/apt-pkg/algorithms.cc#L1498) it looks like using the "run-time" logic `apt` will not autoremove

- the booted kernel
- the latest kernel
- the previous kernel

I do not see any obvious way to configure the behavior to be different.  These are some `apt` configuration options that might be useful.

```
APT
{
...
  NeverAutoRemove "<LIST>";  // list of package name regexes
  LastInstalledKernel "<STRING>"; // last installed kernel version
  VersionedKernelPackages "<LIST>"; // regular expressions to be protected from autoremoval (kernel uname will be appended)
  Protect-Kernels "<BOOL>"; // whether to protect installed kernels against autoremoval (default: true)
```

**links**

- [the commit where the logic was moved out of the shell script](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/commit/04085f46dea9a95dd86123ac00187a63cc4ba2c0)
- [the commit for "Only protect two kernels"](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/commit/824651ded0bcf8603e9b508860b8fe5a68fc53ff)
- [the bug report referenced in the changelog](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unattended-upgrades/+bug/1615381)
- [the bug report referenced in the "Only protect two kernels" commit](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1968154)
- [the apt-auto-removal script before it was deleted](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/blob/a9b56a0101628ac04aad0d4e50363b9c18566832/debian/apt.auto-removal.sh).  This could be used as the basis for your own solution.